# Weird "FROM" after migrating from on-premise Exchange to Microsoft 365 hosted Exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, ios, apple-mail

I migrated my on-premise Exchange 2010 to Microsoft 365 hosted Exchange. I exported my mailstore to PST from Outlook, created a new Outlook profile with the hosted account, and imported the PST. Everything looks good in Outlook, Outlook.com webmail, and Apple Mail on my two Macs, but some messages show a weird "From" field: instead of `Firstname Lastname` its `"Firstname Lastname" [EX:/O:mydomain-com more junk...]`.

All the errant messages are ones I sent, but not all, which is weird. It looks like iOS Mail is using my X.509 address as the display name instead of the actual display name.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Are you using directory sync as well? Where every 30m, on prem AD syncs w office365?

Comment: No, there's no syncing between the two servers; I setup the same username and did a manual export and import. It's strange that only some emails are with the X.509 From header.

Comment: Do you mean that these emails have issues when checking via Apple Mail? To further confirm this issue, it is suggested to check these problematic emails via Outlook for Mac client and Web mail to see if the issue could be reproduced.
Besides, to confirm if this issue is related to your PST file, please try to import it to other personal email accounts and see if the issue has any difference.

Comment: No it was only an issue on iOS Mail; macOS Mail and Outlook were fine. I decided to do it the right way by setting up a minimal hybrid config and running a migration; took all day and caused a lot of aggravation but it was worth it in the end because it migrated rules and other metadata which the PST import missed.